# Flutter Google Maps, how to detect map area change by user, not by controller

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I am using Google Maps to display markers on the map and other widgets to describe each marker on the map. I have successfully implemented when the user tab on a widget, the map area will change to make the matching marker to be the center of the map.
I also have the 'Search this area' button to search the map area.
The hard part is to control how to hide/display the 'Search this area' button.
So far, I have implemented it to display when the map area is changed. However, it causes the button to appear every time the map area changed by the user tab on a widget.

I would like to only detect the map area change by the user manually such as pinch zoom in / out, drag etc.

Comment: Can you add some codes or samples of what you have started?

Comment: Hi e-j5, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @AbdullahRiaz not yet, I haven't looked at it yet after this question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `Listener` widget to listen for `onPointerMove` on your map. Like this,

```
Listener(
  onPointerMove: (move) {
     // This will trigger when a user will drag the map
  },
child: map);
```

Mind that `onPointerMove` is called many times during user drag and is not called when the user taps on map buttons like the map zoom buttons.

If you want only one call after the end of the user interaction and to also get events from the map buttons, you can use `onPointerUp` instead.

Comment: Thank you! I spent days to fix this before I ask the question here.

Comment: @AbdullahRiaz, It's being trigged multiple times on a single event drag

Comment: Great solution. But onPointerUp would also include zoom changes using the map zoom buttons.

Comment: What would be really good is a mapAnimationFinished event.